# Access report showing #Name? in text box bound to query result

Tags: ms-access, textbox, report

I have a table (named `Responses`) with a field named `q01` which contains numbers from 1 to 5. All entries contain valid numbers.

I created a query named `query11` which counts the number of entries in `Responses` with a number 1 in `q01`. (Two columns in the query. First has Field: q01, Table: Responses, Total:Expression, Criteria: 1, Show is unchecked. Second has Field: Count_1_1:q01, Table:Responses, Total:Count, show is checked.) This shows the correct count when the query is run.

I created a report named `rpt_General` which contains a text box (named txtQuery1-1) with the control source `=[query11]![Count_1_1]`

Any time this is run it displays *#Name?* in the text box. I have done some research and seen a number of references to the name of the text box being duplicated elsewhere, but I have changed it numerous times, deleted and recreated the report, and still cannot get it to display correctly.

Comment: Is `query11` included in the report's Record Source?  If not, try this as the text box's Control Source: `=Dlookup("[Count_1_1]", "query11")`

Comment: You don't need a query as far as im aware... `=dcount("*", "[Responses]","q01=1")`

Comment: Both of these were great. I had forgotten to include the query in the record source, and I also simplified it by doing away with the query and using DCount. Thanks to both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to both HansUp and LiamH, I was able to get this working by substituting this as the text box's Control Source.

```
=DCount("*","[Responses]","q01=1")
```

Also, I had not added `query11` into the report's record source.